# Bootstrap dropdown not working in other controller than pages_controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, bootstrapping

I am working for a rails application using this code in my `application.html.erb`

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <% if current_user%>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor: pointer;">Admin</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><%=link_to "Dashboard", projects_path, :class => "dropdown-item"%></li>
                            <li><%=link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :class => "dropdown-item"%></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <% else %>
                    <li>
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" style="cursor: pointer;">Admin</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><%=link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <% end %>

                </ul>
```

Dropdown is working perfectly fine for any page rendered by my `pages_controller`, but not for any of the `projects_controller` one. Here are my controllers

`pages_controller.rb`

```
 require 'json'

 # Controller and action definition for uri say/hello
 # See routing configuration in config/routes.rb
 class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def home
   # get user ip from request
   @yourip = request.remote_ip

   # use params[:name] to get request parameter value by name
   # @parameter = params[:name]

   # get Ruby version and Rails version
   @ruby_version = RUBY_VERSION
   @rails_version = Rails::VERSION::STRING
   end 
 end
```

`projects_controller.rb`

```
 class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :authenticate_user!

 # GET /admin/projects
 def index
    @projects = Project.all

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
 end
end
```

Any ideas which might cause the dropdown to not work on the projects controller pages?

Comment: Sounds like you are including your assets based on the controller name.  Check your application.js and application.css file in your assets folder and see if the require_tree directive is still there or else you're probably not including bootstrap "app wide".

Comment: `*= require_tree .` and `//= require_tree .` are both at the very bottom of those files

Comment: Is there anything being called in your pages.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOLVED]

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bootstrap.min.css' %> was missing from my project's index